# Show on the screen n-element of the progression

Tags: c, c++builder-6

My task is

> Show on the screen n-element of the progression {x<sub>i</sub>}.
>
> X<sub>i</sub> = X<sub>i-1</sub> - 3X<sub>i-2</sub>
>   X<sub>0</sub> = 0
>   X<sub>1</sub> = 2
>   *i* = [2,n]

Here is done, but I didn't understand this theme very well, so i need some help with it.
My code(doesn't work):

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
  int n = Edit1->Text.ToInt();
  int i, x;
  if(n==0){
    i=0;
    Label1->Caption = IntToStr(i);
  }
  if(n==1){
    i=2;
    Label1->Caption = IntToStr(i);
  }
  else {
    for(i=2;i<=n;i++){
      x=(i-1)-3*(i-2);
      Label1->Caption = IntToStr(x);
    }
  }
}
```

It's not very nessesary to write code in C++ Builder

Comment: How does your code not work?  Does it produce the wrong answer?

Comment: You should read up on how various people have implemented calculating the Fibonacci numbers. The method of generating them is __very__ similar to the methods you would use here.

Comment: The problem is `x=(i-1)-3*(i-2);`. It should be  `temp=x; x=x-3*xm;xm=temp;` with appropriate initial values for `x` and `xm` before the loop, such as 2 and 0.

Comment: @Farkid: As I understand the problem statement, `X_2 == 2 + 3*0 == 2` and `X_3 == 2 + 3*2 == 8` and `X_4 == 8 + 3*2 == 14` and `X_5 == 14 + 3*8 == 38`.

Comment: @francis Didn't really understand what you mean.

Comment: @RAJESH if n=2 it shows 1, when n=3 it shows -1. But it should be n=2 -> answer 2, n=3 -> answer -4. Yeah i found a mistake in the task here it should be Xi = Xi-1 - 3Xi-2, but in code i wrote correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misunderstood the progression formula. `Xi-1` and `Xi-2` refer to previous elements calculated in your progression.

So you need two variables, which will be carrying previous values that you have just calculated. At any given loop, you calculate the current `Xi` value using the general progression formula, then copy the value of `Xi-1` into `Xi-2`, throwing the previous value of `Xi-2`. Then you copy the value of `Xi` (the up to now current value) into `Xi-1`.

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
  int n = Edit1->Text.ToInt();
  int i, x;
  int xim1, xim2
  if(n==0){
    i=0;
    Label1->Caption = IntToStr(i);
  }
  if(n==1){
    i=2;
    Label1->Caption = IntToStr(i);
  }
  else {
    xim1 = 2;
    xim2 = 0;
    for(i=2;i<=n;i++){
      x = xim1-3*xim2;
      xim2 = xim1;
      xim1 = x;
    }
    Label1->Caption = IntToStr(x);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given this generating function:

```
    X_0 = 0
    X_1 = 2
    X_i = X_{i-1} + 3*X_{i-2}             i = [2,n]
```

How would you calculate x_4?  We know that X_4 = X_3 + 3*X_2; which means that we need to be able to calculate X_3 and X_2.  We can write these as:

```
    X_2 = X_1 + 3*X_0 = 2 + 3*0 = 2
    X_3 = X_2 + 3*X_1 = 2 + 3*2 = 8
    X_4 = X_3 + 3*X_2 = 8 + 3*2 = 14
```

This can normally be written as a recursive function:

```
    int calcSeries(int n)
    {
        if(0 == n)
            return 0;
        if(1 == n)
            return 2;

         return calcSeries(n-1) + 3*calcSeries(n-2)
    }
```

BTW, this is a very naive implementation for this series, the main problem is that we have two recursive trees; if you look at the hand expansion of X_4 above notice that X_2 appears twice (in the calculation of X_3 and X_4), but we don't store this value so we need to calculate it twice.